# How to pass parameters of on-change Method in create Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created the dynamic picklist using createComponent method and added the on change method `"change": component.getReference('c.onControllerFieldChange')` as well.

Now I need to pass two parameters *controllingField* and *DependentField* to this `c.onControllerFieldChange`,which I will be using later.

How can I add these parameters Dynamically.

```
$A.createComponent(
    "ui:inputSelect",
    {
        "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
        "label": result.FieldSetCustom.FieldLabel,
        "value": result.FieldSetCustom.FieldValue,
        "options": result.SelectOptions,
        "class": result.FieldSetCustom.FieldName,
        "change": component.getReference('c.onControllerFieldChange')
    },
    function(result, status, errorMessage){
        //Add the new button to the body array
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var bodyComponentCallback = component.get('v.bodyComponents');
            bodyComponentCallback.push(result);
            component.set('v.bodyComponents', bodyComponentCallback);
            var rowBody = divRow.get("v.body");
            if(rowBody.length == 1 && !rowPrevBody && setPickListCount == 1){
                rowPrevBody =
                .........
```

In the `ui:inputSelect` I have mention my onchange method.

Please let me know how we can pass the parameters as well to the `onControllerFieldChange` method.